# Can i match www folder structure in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

In my www root folder I have folder app1, app2, app3 and so on. can I match nginx configuration to match the folder with the /appName? for instance 192.168.10.116 should go to the default nginx folder that was set up (nginx Hello world). However 192.168.10.116/app1 should go to app1. In /var/www/app1 I have index.html

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name 192.168.10.116;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/app1;
        index index.html;
        server_name 192.168.10.116/app1;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: That's not a programming question. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is probably better of at serverfault's.

Comment: You are confusing `location` and `server_name`. What you are describing is a single `server` block, with two `locations`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).